# É possível retirar o botão de download em mpdf?

Tags: php, html, mpdf

Eu gostaria de retirar o botão de download, tal como o botão de Imprimir. Existe alguma solução? Já fui ao mpdf.php e removi o case 'D': mas não teve efeito. Também gostaria de impedir qualquer click no pdf em questão.

(Print da área a alterar, supostamente o header)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvSgV.png]

Comment: Essa barra preta aí do navegador certo?

Comment: @rray Essa barra é o header do pdf, ou seja, o topo da página, não do navegador!

Comment: @rray Mudei o print para fazer entender melhor